# Apollo v3 unable to reach server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to deploy my basic apollo server to aws ec2 instance but i am facing with

> "Unable to reach server Network requests from Studio on HTTPS to your
> HTTP endpoint are not secure, so we cannot introspect your endpoint."

So what should i do ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Did you just turn off introspection or how did you fix this issue?